# Why didn't Dumbledore and Harry bring a house-elf to the Horcrux cave?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux, albus-dumbledore, house-elves, apparition

Related: [Regulus Black and the Horcrux Cave](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20832/regulus-black-and-the-horcrux-cave)

Why didn't Dumbledore and Harry Potter bring a house elf with them to the Horcrux cave so they could get in and out more easily (given that elves could apparate in and out)? It seems like it would've been safer too, given that they could make a quick getaway.

Harry Potter didn't seem to have known that house-elves could apparate there at the time (because he was baffled by Kreacher's later claim to have apparated out of the same cave, so he apparently didn't know about that until the 7th book), but wouldn't Dumbledore have known that? Why didn't *he* think of it?

Comment: Why didn't the trio summon a house elf when confronting Sirius in the Shrieking Shack?  Why didn't Harry summon a house elf in the graveyard?  Why didn't the gang summon a house elf in the Department of Mysteries?

Comment: @TGnat They didn't own an Elf to summon, and it's not like they had time to canvass around for a volunteer in advance. The Horcrux Cave was different because they knew they were going there in advance (plus there were plenty of house elves working for Dumbledore).

Comment: @EJS - Dobby would have volunteered, and easily found.

Comment: @Tim That was my thought as well - which makes the omission even odder (especially given that [Aberforth knew to send Dobby to Malfoy Manner later](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/77421/how-did-aberforth-dumbledore-know-to-send-a-house-elf-to-help-harry-at-malfoy-ma?rq=1))

Comment: I guess it's like Tolkien's giant eagles - House Elfs are too powerful.

Comment: Isn't [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/156135/why-couldnt-the-order-summon-kreacher-and-possibly-dobby-to-apparate-harry-to-t) really the same question?  They both basically ask why aren't house elves used to escape from sticky situations?

Comment: @TGnat Not really - they were different circumstances.

Comment: They were going into the unknown. Since what they were facing was a mystery there was no purpose to be served in taking a random tag-along elf along on their top secret excursion.

Comment: Never mind the fact that the whole operation was supposed to be Top Secret. Dumbledore didn't want **anybody** except Harry, Ron and Hermione knowing about the Horcruxes, fearing Voldemort would find out and relocate them.

Comment: Ask this to Hermione and she will kill you...

Comment: They hadn't read the books and didn't know that a house elf's magic could get around the anti-Apparation charm.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Dumbledore was already poisoned with the cursed ring (as revealed later in book 7) and knew he was going to die. He was ready to take all the risks himself.
2. Dumbledore did not know in advance of the protection Voldemort built around the cave. He assumed that only a wizard could breach it.
3. It was not obvious that a house elf could breach the protection of the cave. Voldemort himself, with his bias of "wizarding supremacy", could not think of such possibility.
4. Their purpose and destination was top secret. A house elf, no matter how loyal, could be forced or deceived to compromise their mission.

Comment: They are also both Good People who would not want to risk an additional innocent life for their own purposes. You don't *equip* yourself with a house elf. They are people.